# Raising Indices on Conformally Flat Metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor

I was looking at an exercise on page 2 of this document [http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jbourj/gr/homework%205.pdf](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejbourj/gr/homework%205.pdf), where it states:

$$g_{\mu v}=e^{2\Omega(x)} \eta_{\mu v}.  \tag{1}$$

And then it is used in the solution that

$$g^{\mu v}=e^{-2\Omega(x)} \eta^{\mu v}.  \tag{2}$$

I am struggling with how the negative got there, and how would it look if instead of $e^{2\Omega(x)}$ we had some $f(\Omega(x))$

Comment: Hint: $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\nu\lambda}=\delta^\mu_\lambda$

Comment: Hint 2: OP's eq. (2) denotes the inverse metric.